# Subtraction With 8 Bit Integers

Tags: binary, binary-operations

I have encountered the following question and I don't know how to approach it:

"Perform the following subtraction by adding the 2's complement using 8 bit integers: 35-15=20"

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you express the numbers at twos complement?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Well it looks like I need to figure out how to represent 35, 15, and 20 as a two's complement. And then just rewrite the equation with that binary notation no?

Comment: I just don't know how to represent anything higher than 2 as a two's complement.

Comment: Would it be (2^8-35)^2 - (2^8-15)^2 = (2^8-20)^2? According to wikipedia this would be the correct notation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asked to do $35 +(-15)$ representing the numbers in twos complement.  For positive numbers, the numeral in twos complement is the same as the binary number, so $35$ is represented as $0010\ 0011_2$ in eight bits.  To make a number negative, you complement it bitwise, then add one.  To represent $15$ we note that $15$ is represented as $0000\ 1111_2$.  Its bitwise complement is $1111\ 0000_2$ so $-15$ is represented as $1111\ 0001$.  We then add $0010\ 0011_2+1111\ 0001_2=0001\ 0100_2=20_{10}$